# Out of control ShellExtIO.log file from bitorrent sync

Tags: resilio-sync

I run resilio sync (formerly known as bitorrent sync) to sync large files between systems. While pruning unwanted files I found a immense log file which I can't delete cause apparently explorer is using it. How do I delete this file easily?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its a [known issue](https://forum.resilio.com/topic/42362-bittorrent-sync-logging-every-single-filename-i-see/), but since I'd rather not manually mess with the registry, I used a few well known tools to delete this file. The issue should be fixed with newer builds

I did two things - firstly I used [shellextview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html#DownloadLinks) to disable any explorer shell extensions related to bitorrent sync. Resilio Sync (the newer build) has its own, so no clue why these where still there. I'm *not* sure if its essential, and if it actually helped, since I couldn't delete the file after that

Then I used [sysinternals process explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to identify any process with  handles on the file - using ctrl F 
to search for it,

[image]

For some reason firefox, whatpulse *and* explorer had handles so I closed firefox and whatpulse, and removed the handles for explorer through process explorer - just rightclick and close any that are there

[image]

This let me delete the file the usual way.

Comment: I hate paying for products that have a feel of still being in a beta state.  This issue among others make me have a love hate relationship with Resilio Sync.